# How do I join a column onto a selected query in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following view and I need to add on the characterName column from the character table as reference ***without*** changing the structure of the query results. Please help.

```
        CREATE VIEW vwTopStackedItems
    AS
        SELECT TOP 20 MAX(inventorySlot.quantity) AS 'Top Stacked', item.itemName AS 'Item Name'
        FROM inventorySlot
        JOIN item
        ON inventorySlot.itemID = item.itemID
        JOIN character
        ON inventorySlot.characterID = character.characterID
        WHERE quantity > 1
        GROUP BY itemName
        ORDER BY MAX(quantity) DESC             
    GO


SELECT * FROM vwTopStackedItems
GO
```

Comment: How about MAX(CharacterName)? But this of course DOES change the structure of the query results because there is now a new column.

Comment: Somehow this request doesn't make sense at all: if you add a column, this changes the structure - no way around this! If you want to consider another column in the join / the where, please provide info on the corresponding table.

Comment: If CharacterName is a VARCHAR, would that work with MAX()?

Comment: Of course it will. Would be pretty simple to try it right? :) Take a peek at the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks Sean, I'm having a look now.

Comment: Tyron, perhaps I am wording it wrong, sorry. I am happy with the results of the query, I just want to try reference the characterName that has the items, without disturbing the item grouping.

Comment: Sean Lange you rule!! Thank you, You're advice to add MAX(characterName) was spot on!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use function CONCAT() to concatenate the two values. For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql

```
CREATE VIEW vwTopStackedItems
    AS
        SELECT TOP 20 MAX(inventorySlot.quantity) AS 'Top Stacked', CONCAT(item.itemName, '-', character.characterName)  AS 'Item Name'
        FROM inventorySlot
        JOIN item
        ON inventorySlot.itemID = item.itemID
        JOIN character
        ON inventorySlot.characterID = character.characterID
        WHERE quantity > 1
        GROUP BY CONCAT(item.itemName, '-', character.characterName)
        ORDER BY MAX(quantity) DESC             
    GO


SELECT * FROM vwTopStackedItems
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Edu Pelais, Appreciate the help! I have only being doing sql for a week and we haven't covered concat() yet so I can't submit it in my project.

Comment: @Jarrod CONCAT function is very easy to use and very useful too.

Answer (score 0):

since itemName is your key to this view, you need another view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW vwTopStackedItemsWCharacter
    AS
        SELECT itemName, characterName 
        FROM inventorySlot
        JOIN item
        ON inventorySlot.itemID = item.itemID
        JOIN character
        ON inventorySlot.characterID = character.characterID
        GROUP BY itemName, characterName
```

this second view will bring on the character name so you join accordingly. this way you get the info without any change on vwTopStackedItems